# Modifying html attributes with jQuery producing unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am experiencing some unusual results with my jQuery and was hoping that somebody could enlighten me as to why.  I am sure that jQuery is powerful enough to do this, so I wonder what I am doing wrong.  Here is what I have (some seemingly simple and easy to understand code):

```
///////////reset default search entries/////////////
$("#sOrderByDLM").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("#sOrderByID").attr('checked', '');
$("#sOrderByPOIName").attr('checked', '');
$("#sOrderByAge").attr('checked', '');
$("#sOrderByOfficer").attr('checked', '');

$("#sOrderByDesc").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("#sOrderByAsc").attr('checked', '');
```

I have this inside a simple javaScript function that is called on the click of a non-submit type (normal) button.  The problem is that when I click this, instead of it filling the `sOrderByDLM` radio button, it actually fills the `sOrderByOfficer` button and likewise with the bottom two jQuery statements (e.g., `sOrderByAsc` becomes '`checked`' instead of `sOrderByDesc`) Am I not blatantly telling jQuery to reset the '`checked`' attribute to that of the second argument, which is blank, except in the cases where I specifically set it to '`checked`' for the fields I intend to be default?

I experienced a similar problem with checkboxes, but I found a work around by simply calling the same statements in reverse order, but that doesn't seem to work here, though.  If I set '`checked="checked"`' in razor everything is fine, but I need this button to work on the client side.

Anyway, if the HTML is necessary, I will provide it, but I doubt it is needed since the I have triple checked the ids to be sure.

Thanks for any help!

(And God Bless Stack Overflow, I don't know what I would do without you! :D)

UPDATE:

```
                    <tr>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor"><label for="sOrderByDLM">Date Last Modified</label><br/><input type="radio" id="sOrderByDLM" name="sOrderBy" style="margin-left: 115px;" value="OrderByDLM" @OrderByFiller[0] /></td>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor"><label for="sOrderByID">Entry ID</label><br/><input type="radio" id="sOrderByID" name="sOrderBy" style="margin-left: 115px;" value="OrderByID" @OrderByFiller[1] /></td>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor"><label for="sOrderByPOIName">POI Name</label><br/><input type="radio" id="sOrderByPOIName" name="sOrderBy" style="margin-left: 115px;" value="OrderByPOIName" @OrderByFiller[2] /></td>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor"><label for="sOrderByAge">Age</label><br/><input type="radio" id="sOrderByAge" name="sOrderBy" style="margin-left: 115px;" value="OrderByAge" @OrderByFiller[3] /></td>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor"><label for="sOrderByOfficer">Officer</label><br/><input type="radio" id="sOrderByOfficer" name="sOrderBy" style="margin-left: 115px;" value="OrderByOfficer" @OrderByFiller[4] /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor2">In Descending Or<br/>Ascending Order:</td>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor2"><label for="sOrderByDesc">Descending Order</label><br/><input type="radio" id="sOrderByDesc" name="sAscOrDesc" style="margin-left: 115px;" value="OrderByDesc" @OrderByAscOrDescFiller[0] /></td>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor2"><label for="sOrderByAsc">Ascending Order</label><br/><input type="radio" id="sOrderByAsc" name="sAscOrDesc" style="margin-left: 115px;" value="OrderByAsc" @OrderByAscOrDescFiller[1] /></td>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor2"><button type="button" class="smallbtn" onclick="clearSortEntries()">Reset Sort Entries</button></td>
                        <td class="orderlineupColor2"></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Are the id's unique on the page..??

Comment: You're answer did, work, I have one button that clears that set of fields alone, and another that clears the whole form, and I was clicking the former while modifying code for the latter, my apologies.  I have accepted and upvoted your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `bools` and `.prop()`

```
$("#sOrderByDLM").prop('checked', true); // To check

$("#sOrderByID").prop('checked', false); // To Uncheck
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to used 'checked' and '' then use removeAttr jquery function instead of assigning `''` blank to `checked` attribute but I do not prefer this one. As assigning true and false looks more symmetrical to me then assigning checked and removing attribute.

```
$("#sOrderByDLM").attr('checked', 'checked');

$("#sOrderByID").removeAttr('checked');
```

Use true or false instead of `'checked'` and `''`

```
$("#sOrderByDLM").attr('checked', true);

$("#sOrderByID").attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

To uncheck, try:

```
$("#sOrderByAsc").removeAttr('checked', '');
```

`checked` and `selected` are binary properties, **not true/false** attributes.

`$("#sOrderByDLM").attr('checked', 'checked');` is correct.

So is: `.attr('selected', 'selected');`

Comment: This is just another way to do the same thing that is all over this page, and thus produces the same unexpected results.

Comment: No, checked **is** a Boolean attribute. The problem is that the checked attribute maps to the `defaultChecked` property (which does not change when the user checks or unchecks the checkbox).

Answer (score -1):

there is a difference between `.attr()` and `.prop()`

[image: aaa]

- http://api.jquery.com/prop/
- http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: to someone that should be reading javascript tutorials, you're right, it isn't. to someone that knows at least the basics, the answer is right before the eyes.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with @VoidKing and say this isn't an answer; the table doesn't address *setting* values at all, it just states what is returned when you use the various functions to *get* values. Yes, somebody who is reasonably well versed in the documentation can likely deduce what you're trying to get at, but that doesn't make this useful at all.